# python using easy_install ImportError: No module named _md5

Tags: python, easy-install

I searched a lot and did not find any answer to this problem =(

I have a CentOS 5 as a server, following this How To:
http://wiki.osqa.net/display/docs/RHEL%2C+CentOS+5+Installation+Guide#RHEL%2CCentOS5InstallationGuide-Python

I'm able to install python 2.6 separated from the yum version. But when I run ./easy_install ElementTree I get this strange error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./easy_install", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('distribute==0.6.14', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 305, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2244, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from setuptools.package_index import PackageIndex
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 2, in <module>
    import sys, os.path, re, urlparse, urllib2, shutil, random, socket, cStringIO
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 93, in <module>
    import hashlib
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py", line 136, in <module>
    md5 = __get_builtin_constructor('md5')
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py", line 63, in __get_builtin_constructor
    import _md5
ImportError: No module named _md5
```

I do not understand python and have no idea how to fix this issue, I'm trying to install OSQA to run a phpBB support forum for another country.

Thanks for any help, best regard's.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of ActivePython? http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess having had a similar issue on CentOS before, is that the ld path for the new Python isn't set, and it can't find its loadable modules folder.

The 3rd code block on this blog post shows setting an ld path for an opt Python (though it is 2.7): http://toey.tc20.net/2010/08/04/install-python-2-7-gevent-on-centos-5-x86_64/

I would assume that an installer would have done this as part of the install step, but maybe the blog post above will be of some help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but had no success, I add the PATH to my .bashrc and .bash_profile but it did not changed anything =(
Is there anything else I can do? I just need mod_wsgi and DJango running on the server.
Thanks!

Comment: I compiled Python & mod_wsgi from source on CentOS to /usr/local, for running Django. Script is here: https://gist.github.com/546154 you'll need to download all of those packages, or newer versions and update the script. The script is just a "starting point", as I took out some work-specific file hosts.

Comment: wow great! But this will install python separated from the yum? Thanks!

Comment: Yes; yum hardcodes its use of Python to /usr/bin/python. This will install to /usr/local/bin/python. You'll probably want to put /usr/local/bin in your user's PATH ahead of /usr/bin; this hasn't interfered with yum or other system tools.

Comment: Humm, ok! I'm searching for these files and will put then inside a URL then the script can runs.
Thanks again, in a while I will post a feedback.

Comment: Adam, everything worked just fine! Now, how can I see if it is working? Can I install any python application and test?
Thanks again.

Comment: Install Django, then do "python" (assuming a fixed PATH, else /usr/local/bin/python) and "import django". Then "print django.get_version()". Or, really, any other Python app that requires >> 2.4 should be a reasonable test.

Comment: By the way, if you have any suggestions for my script, let me know, I can clean it up to work more out-of-the-box.

Comment: Ok, sorry for my noob questions, my place is php but I would like to get used to python. I will create at apache a place where I can listen to python server port and then do what you said, hope it works.

For your script, very good and easy to understand, but I think you should point the packges releases to their real path, but it can broke the links, but is just an idea.
Again Adam, thanks for your help, i wish one day I can help like you helped.

Comment: I got the same issue, but not able to resolve it by "ld" mentioned above. I'm using python 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that the issue is unrelated to _md5.so, but instead that hashlib is failing to import _hashlib.so within a try block, then getting to a different and normally unused section of code (where the _md5 problem shows up).  Try:

```
import _hashlib.so
```

I got something like:

```
ImportError: <PATH>/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied
```

I googled that and found http://www.quantumwise.com/forum/index.php?topic=16.0 which says you need to do:

```
chcon -t texrel_shlib_t <PATH>/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Activepython 2.6 seems to have some problem in their latest build.  please check for its former release.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter the same issue like you, I fix it after I add the lib path of python where the module will be installed.

It is really caused by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, please try to add "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib" into your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to http://johnsofteng.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/python-importerror-no-module-named-_md5/

I met the similar problem on Redhat 6.4, python binary (2.7.x) packages is copied from other already installed system (which is built from source).

The problem is the _hashlib.so, which miss the libssl.so.0.9.8

```
bash-4.1# ldd /proj/application/tools/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff51d6f000)
    libssl.so.0.9.8 => not found
    libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0x00007f9a69746000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /proj/application/tools/python2.7/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f9a6936b000)
```

I just install missed package and soft link to the library.

```
bash-4.1# yum install -y tar openssh-clients
bash-4.1# ln -s /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8
```

Then the setuptool installation is successful