# How to install Python using source files to a custom directory

Tags: python, installation

I want to build Python 2.7.1 additionally to the one the redhat server already has pre-installed.

What options do I need to modify/use so that Python can be built under i.e. /opt/Python27

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: See the answer and discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278874/phytom-using-easy-install-importerror-no-module-named-md5/4278985#4278985

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Configure with:

`./configure --prefix=/opt/Python27`

In general, you can just do `./configure --help` to get a list of all the options you're allowed to set for that configure script.

Answer (score 1):

You also want to pass --enable-shared to configure since it is an additional installation of Python.