# aix 6.1: python: ImportError: No module named _md5

Tags: python, aix, import

I am trying to set up python environment on AIX 6.1 TL7, python-2.7.1-1.aix6.1.ppc.rpm installation was successful, however when I try to use BaseHttpServer I am getting following error:

> ImportError: No module named _md5

Please advise

Thank You, 
m.

Comment: can you provide a full traceback?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278874/python-using-easy-install-importerror-no-module-named-md5 might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it around by extracting md5.so from hashlib.a. fortunately dynamic library was in the archive.